# How Does ADMT Use SQL? Can I point it to an existing instance?

Tags: domain, admt

I'm using ADMT (Active Directory Migration Tool) to move users from a child domain into a parent domain. Since one of the requirements is to use a SQL Server I'd like to point it to one that already exists within that forest.

However, that SQL Server has an instance running that supports one of the main information systems at the site, and is therefore precious. Would ADMT require that I start a new instance? Would it be able to use the existing instance that the information system is using? What are the risks involved here if any?

Additionally, once the migration is complete, do I need to keep ADMT (or the SQL Server if I install a local one) installed? I'm assuming the answer to this is no, but I can't find it anywhere in the documentation.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADMT does not require a new SQL instance, it can make a database in an existing instance.

If you stop using ADMT, of course you no longer need the software or the SQL instance it uses.

Comment: All makes sense. I went ahead and did this in a test environment anyway to validate. Thanks for the confirmation!